# check the type of files is present or not using nodejs

Tags: node.js, fs

I want to find the type of files which is present or not, I am using nodejs, fs. Here is my code

```
var location = '**/*.js';
log(fs.statSync(location).isFile());
```

which always returns the error.

```
 Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory '**/*.js'
```

How to I find the files is present or not. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

node doesn't have support for globbing (**/*.js) built-in. You'll need to either recursively walk the directories and iterate over the array of file names to find the file types you want, or use something like [node-glob](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob).

Using [recusrive-readdir-sync](https://www.npmjs.com/package/recursive-readdir-sync)

```
var recursiveReadSync = require('recursive-readdir-sync'),
    files;
files = recursiveReadSync('./');

files.forEach(function (fileName) {
    if (fileName.search(/\.js$/g) !== -1) {
        console.log("Found a *.js file");
    }
});
```

Using node-glob:

```
var glob = require("glob")
glob("**/*.js", function (er, files) {
    files.forEach(function (fileName) {
    if (fileName.search(/\.js$/g) !== -1) {
        console.log("Found a *.js file");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

node.js dose not support "glob" wildcards by default. You can use external package like [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob) one